# strange php error

Tags: php, wampserver

I have the following code:

```
    var_dump($cumulitive);
    $y_axis_max = max($cumulitive)*1.3;
    var_dump($y_axis_max);
```

It outputs the following:

```
array(16) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(0)
  [2]=>
  int(0)
  [3]=>
  int(0)
  [4]=>
  int(0)
  [5]=>
  int(0)
  [6]=>
  int(0)
  [7]=>
  int(0)
  [8]=>
  int(0)
  [9]=>
  int(0)
  [10]=>
  int(0)
  [11]=>
  int(4)
  [12]=>
  int(4)
  [13]=>
  int(4)
  [14]=>
  int(9)
  [15]=>
  int(9)
}
float(NAN)
```

As you can see, $y_axis_max is giving NAN.  So I try this:  I restart WampServer.  It works now.  I refresh the browser.  Works again.  refresh the browser again.  Now it doesn't work, and I can't get it to work again without restarting Apache.  From the 3rd request on it stops working.

It USED to work just fine.  Then I changed some things.  Specifically, I modified my app to use the DateTime class in a few places.  But that shouldn't make this strange error occur.  Any ideas on how to debug this?

If I call the $y_axis_max = .. line of code twice in a row, then I get this for $y_axis_max:

```
float(@.7)
```

What the heck is that?

EDIT: Seems that calling DateTime::diff earlier causes the error.  Any workaround ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that calling DateTime::diff earlier causes the error.  I just used a work-around so not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

max() will work on arrays. Looks like you have some form of corruption in your code. If one of the elements in the array is a NAN you will get this result. Try testing a smaller script on your server in order to isolate the problem.

Comment: Seems that calling DateTime::diff earlier causes the error. VERY STRANGE